# Abelian Group and "Group"

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I am having trouble distinguishing some terms here. I got these from my book

> A **group** is a nonempty set G together with binary operation * that satisfies the three properties
>
> G1. Associativity
>
> G2. Identity
>
> G3. Inverse
>
> If a **group** also satisfies Commutativity, then it is **abelian**, if it doesn't then it is **nonabelian**

Okay here is my confusion, the last statement seems to throw the term **group** aside. Is it basically telling me to check whether Commutativity is satisfied or not and label them **abelian** and **nonabelian**?

Comment: But what about "If a **group**"...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group $\{G,*\}$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. $a*b\in G, \forall a,b\in G$
2. $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c), \forall a,b,c\in G$
3. $\exists! e\in G:e*a=a*e=a,\forall a\in G$
4. $\exists! a^{-1}:a a^{-1}=a^{-1}a=e, \forall a\in G$

An abelian group is just a specific type of group which also satisfies
$$a*b=b*a,\ \ \forall a,b\in G$$
If it does not meet this condition it is non-abelian.

A useful analogy might be to consider the natural numbers. A number is prime if it has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. If it does not meet this condition it is non-prime (also known as composite). Similarly, a group is abelian if all its elements commute, otherwise it is non-abelian.

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be getting confused over two types of [adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective) usage.  Wikipedia highlights the difference with this example:

- That's an interesting idea. (attributive)
- That idea is interesting. (predicative)

So, it's legitimate to say e.g.:

- $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an abelian group.
- $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is abelian.

And they have the same meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Abelianness (commutativity) is a property a group can have. If G is a group and * also is commutative, then G "is abelian". We can call G an "abelian group" or just say "G is abelian". The same goes for nonabelian.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective abelian typically only applies to groups. If a ring satisfies the commutativity condition, then we call the ring commutative (or noncommutative if it doesn't) rather than abelian or nonabelian. So if you see a structure described simply as abelian, it's probably understood to be a group. With regards to your specific question, when referring to a group $G$ satisfying the commutativity property, calling $G$ abelian or calling $G$ an abelian group are both acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Not every group is commutative. For instance, check the group of $2\times 2$ matrices under multiplication with determinant does not equal to zero. This group in not abelian (commutative) group since $AB \neq BA$ in general.